# JQuery-UI ToolTip position

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

Is there anyway to have the tooltip position for the standard JQuery-UI tooltip (http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to be follow the mouse rather than the cell?

Currently the position is based on the page element that contains the "title" attribute using the rules for positions in JQuery-UI (http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).

From everything I have seen this is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [track](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-track%22track%22) option.

> Whether the tooltip should track (follow) the mouse.

Comment: This is just what I needed. I didn't notice the "track" option as I wasn't sure the wording on what I meant. Thanks allot I'll look for this in the future.